# Why cant I open 32bit Outlook on a 64bit System using a JAR when it worked in Eclipse...?

Tags: java, eclipse, outlook, swt

The Java app I am developing is an internal tool for others to use to help our daily activities. When the tool is used (on a JButton press which calls the code below) I want it to open a new Outlook EMail for the user to see/edit.

At first I was developing this app in a 64 bit Eclipse and could not get SWT to open Outlook despite all my research. After I had some issues running 64bit versus 32bit SWT, I had the idea to check Outlook, and sure enough the company using is 32 bit. I loaded up a 32 bit eclipse, imported my project, switch SWT to 32 bit and it worked exactly as intended.

I noticed the process that was running was javaw.exe*32 but the 64bit Eclipse was using the process javaw.exe. I exported the JAR from the 32bit Eclipse and gave it a shot and no EMail showed up. I checked the JRE's installed and saw both 32bit and 64bit but my company had a policy that forced only the 64bit JRE in the Java Control Panel. I worked with some others and got both installed and enabled as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9J5u.jpg). Still the JAR fails to open the EMail. I even tried disabling the 64bit and it still does not work.

Is there anything that can be done to remedy this situation? Please let me know if I can elaborate better or provide more info!

```
package EDM_PKG;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class CreateEmail {
private static Display display = new Display();
public static void sendEMail(String env) {
    //String currUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String msg = getMessage(env);
    String sub = getSubject(env);
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);

    // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
    //OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,"OVCtl.OVCtl");
    //site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

    // Now get the outlook application
    OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
    OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);

    OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */).getAutomation();

    setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
    setProperty(mail, "Subject", sub);
    setProperty(mail, "To", "example@gmail.com");
    setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody", msg);

    invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);
    display = null;
}
private static String getMessage(String env) {
    String msg = "";
    if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("quas")) {
        msg = "<html><body>The <b>USER</b> excel has been migrated to <b>QUAS.</b><br><br> This email was generated by Excel Datatable Migrator.</body></html>";
    } else if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("prod")) {
        msg = "<html><body>The <b>QUAS</b> excel has been migrated to <b>PROD.</b><br><br>This email was generated by Excel Datatable Migrator.</body></html>";
    }  else {
        msg = "Somthing happened with the automated message of EDM. Please contact the user with the eCode: "+System.getProperty("user.name")+".</body></html>";
    }

    return msg;
}
private static String getSubject(String env) {
    String sub = "";
    if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("quas")) {
        sub = "EDM has been used to move USER to QUAS...";
    } else if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("prod")) {
        sub = "EDM has been used to move QUAS to PROD...";
    }  else {
        sub = "Somthing didnt quite work right...";
    }

    return sub;
}
private static OleAutomation getProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
    Variant varResult = auto.getProperty(property(auto, name));
    if (varResult != null && varResult.getType() != OLE.VT_EMPTY) {
        OleAutomation result = varResult.getAutomation();
        varResult.dispose();
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command,
        String value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
            new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command));
}

private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command, int value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
            new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
}

private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
        String value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
}

private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
        int value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
}

private static int property(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
    return auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { name })[0];
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, post the code you use to open Outlook from Java. Second: You've tagged this as `SWT`, but you're talking about a `JButton`, so which one is it?

Comment: The button press calls sendEMail, thanks for taking a look please let me know if there is any other info I can give.

Comment: I assume simply calling this won't do? `Program.launch("mailto:bla@blubb.com&subject=Subject&body=Message here");`

Comment: Similar situation. That code is much nicer than what I was using but when I run as a JAR the email does not come up. It works when running from 32bit Eclipse, but not running the JAR I exported from Eclipse.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your jar then. The code I posted will work just fine on any system. Do you get any exception?

Comment: You were right, the code you suggested fixed my problem. There was an exception thrown from an import of 32bit SWT that I missed. So once I removed the import, the Program.launch worked fine. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the heavyweight and difficult to use `Ole` classes.
If all you want is to send an email, just call this:

```
Program.launch("mailto:bla@blubb.com&subject=Subject&body=Me‌​ssage here");
```

This will work on all architectures and operating systems.