# Send outlook mail from 32 bit java program

Tags: java, outlook

I want to open a pre-populated outlook message pop-up from a 32 bit java program.

Previously, I used http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html
to open the message with HTML body. But this only worked till the app users were using 32 bit outlook.

The users have decided to move to 64 bit outlook and above link does not work for that case, i.e. unable to open 64 bit outlook from 32 bit java.

Is there a way where I can open outlook message irrespective of its bit-version using 32 bit java program ?

Comment: Are you getting a particular error? 64 bit Outlook (being an out-of-proc COM server) can be accessed from a 32 bit process.

Comment: Have you checked this url?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678762/why-cant-i-open-32bit-outlook-on-a-64bit-system-using-a-jar-when-it-worked-in-ec

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to create Ole Client. result = -2147221164
            at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(Unknown Source) ~[swt-4.3-win32-x86-safe.jar:na]

Comment: @AlinaLi Tried using Program.launch, but does not work since the body is in HTML format.

Comment: The error is REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG, which means the OM system does not see the registry entries corresponding to the COM server.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this ?